# GCP | How to evaluate vCPU needs for N1 to N2 and N2 to N2D switch?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is there a way to calculate how much compute to provision for the same instance when switching from N1 to N2 or N2 to N2D (assuming the same workload)?

All I could find is general information like "N2 offers 20% more performance to N1" or "N2D offers 13% better performance to comparable N series and 39% better performance vs N1".

Say I am currently using 100 N1 vCPU, does that mean I can expect to provision 80 N2 vCPU or 61 N2D vCPU for the same general purpose workload?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/general-purpose-machines Can you check this out. If you scroll down to N3, it has details related to N2's offerings

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand the general details related to N2/N2D offerings. What I am interested in is the 1vCPU performance comparison between each family for non-specialized workloads. Like 1vCPU N1 vs 1vCPU N2 vs 1vCPU N2D.

Answer (score 2):

As you're interested to know about 1vCPU N1 vs 1vCPU N2 vs 1vCPU N2D refer to this [link](https://www.densify.com/articles/google-compute-engine-machine-types)

Below which might help you in understanding its concept :

·      N1 is the first-generation machine which can provide up to 96 vCPUs and 624 GB memory and is powered by Intel Skylake CPU or one of its predecessors. Google recommends usage of its second-generation machines (N2, N2D and E2) while using general loads, but it is interesting to note that apart from the Accelerated-optimized machine family, N1 machines are the only ones that can be used to support GPU workloads with a selected NVIDIA GPUs. N1s also support TPUs in select zones.

·      N2 is the second-generation machine powered by 2nd Generation Intel Xeon Scalable Processors (Cascade Lake) CPU platform with a base frequency of 2.8 GHz and a sustained all core turbo of 3.4 GHz. It offers up to 80 vCPUs and 640 GB memory. N2s provide more memory per vCPU as compared to N1s.

·      N2D is the latest second-generation machine which became generally available earlier this year on 6th April 2020. They are powered by 2nd Generation AMD EPYC Rome CPU platform and have a capability to provide up to 224 vCPUs and 768 GB memory, the highest combination possible in the general purpose family. In the [google announcement](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/announcing-the-n2d-vm-family-based-on-amd), the N2D-standard-32 (32 vCPUs) performed 39% better than N1-standard-32 when evaluated using Coremark and 13% savings over N1 family

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've come across that several time in my quest for answer to this question. :) We don't currently have a use case for GPU workloads, and our Google rep supports our effort moving to N2/N2D. They did not provide any guidance to use as to how much resource to provision to handle the same workload.

Comment: @MinhTran : check below links 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#machine_type_comparison,
https://gcpinstances.doit-intl.com/ ,
https://gcloud-compute.com/

Comment: Hey,thanks for your input. Your answer above adds some info regarding the machine family, but doesn't directly address how much resource to provision when switching between different machine family types. I'm working on answering my own question and will provide an answer when/if I came to one. :)

Answer (score 1):

For our web applications, N2 seems to be 20 to 30% faster than N1, depending on whether you choose default N2 arch (which seems to be `Cascade Lake`) or force `Ice Lake` respectively. The N2D is about 30% faster if you select `Milan` arch, matching the fastest versions of N2. Given than N2D is quite a bit cheaper than N2, it is a no-brainer for us.
Especially after Google finally fixed a "slow core" issue their N2Ds had.

You can see some very detailed comparisons I did [here](https://blogs.perl.org/users/dimitrios_kechagias/2022/03/cloud-provider-performance-comparison-gcp-aws-azure-perl.html).

The answer to your question of course would be something like: benchmark your code and make a guess based on the results, then scale up / down depending on your monitoring, that's why you are using the cloud in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

GCP's Documentation site now seems to have an `official CPU Benchmark` for various machine families :)

"CoreMark scores of VMs by family"
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/coremark-scores-of-vm-instances